# Replace first occurrence of character in Android/Java?

Tags: java, android, string

I would like to take the 's' out of http.

```
 https://joy.tothewor.ld/today/and/tommorrow

 http://joy.tothewor.ld/today/and/tommorrow
```

What's the fastest/less expensive way?

substring, string builder, something newer in Android's SDK?

Comment: The least expensive is `if(string.startsWith("https:")) string = "http"+string.substring(5);`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`String.replaceFirst`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) will do the job.

```
String output = input.replaceFirst("s","");
```

Answer (score 4):

`String.replaceFirst` is heavyweight

```
 public String replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement) {
        return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(this).replaceFirst(replacement);
 }
```

this is the fastest way

```
str = str.substring(0, 4) + s.substring(5);
```

Comment: public String replaceSS(String s) {
  String xincomingScene;
  xincomingScene = xincomingScene.substring(s, 4) + s.substring(4);
  return xincomingScene;
  }

Comment: the method substring(int,int) in the Type String is not applicable for the arguments(String, int)

Comment: That’s of course only correct, if you *know* that the intended character is at the index `4`. But if you know beforehand that `str` starts with `"https"` and is supposed to be changed to `"http…"`, it might be even faster to say `str = "http" + s.substring(5);`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
String str="https://joy.tothewor.ld/today/and/tommorrow"
                                            .replace("https://","http://");
```

Comment: that is also a good one .. actually there are plenty of options .. :) .. +1

Comment: but whats the least expensive